# reverse Geocoding with multiple requests at a time

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have tried reverse Geocoding with multiple requests at a time...
My coding is below:

```
var latlon=new Array();
var lname="";
latlon[0]=new array("11.19","71.20");
latlon[1]=new array("12.89","72.22");
latlon[2]=new array("13.49","73.64");
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
 lname=locationname(latlon[i][0],latlon[i][1]);
 alert(lname);
}

function locationname(lat,lon)
{
        var llng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lon);
       ligeocoder.geocode({'latLng': llng}, function(results, status)
       {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            { 
                if (results[0]) 
                {
                    loname=results[0].formatted_address;
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("result failed");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
            }
        });
}
```

It shows error: **Geocoder failed due to: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT**

Answer (score 0):

This is a limit of the Google geocoding API, not javascript. Basically google will not let you make too many requests at a time, there is no way to get around this limit without breaking the google api terms of service.

If you want to limit the amount of calls you're doing at a time, put  your geocoding function in a setInterval.